# How to compare two lists which have strings in them in python?

Tags: python, list, string-comparison

I have these two lists:

```
list1 = ['M', 'AR0', 'I', 'K', 'Y']
list2 = ['M', 'AR0', 'IY', 'K', 'U']
```

I want the output "Yes" when the two elements in the same position are equal and "No" when the two elements in the same position are not equal. I want to do this using a for loop only because the strings that I will need to run my code on are longer than these.

This is the code I have so far, but when I run it, it gives me this error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

So, how do I go through each element and check if they are equal to each other or not and then print what I want?

```
for i in list1:
  if list1[i] == list2[i]:
     print("Yes")
  else:
     print("No")
```

For example, in the two lists above, the elements in the second and fourth position are not equal.

Comment: Why do you think `i` is an index?

Comment: `TypeError` because `i` is not an index, it is the item in the list so basically you're comparing `item1['m'] == item2['m']` ...so on.. check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73104396/16177121) for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`:

```
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    if i == j:
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```

Output:

```
Yes
Yes
No
Yes
No
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `zip()` here along with a list comprehension:

```py
list1 = ['M', 'AR0', 'I', 'K', 'Y']
list2 = ['M', 'AR0', 'IY', 'K', 'U']
z = ["Yes" if x[0] == x[1] else "No" for x in zip(list1, list2)]
print(z)  # ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No']
```

Answer (score 0):

You've 4 methods of doing so

**your method**

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] == list2[i]:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

**using list comprehension**

```
li = ['yes' if list1[i] == list2[i] else 'no' for i in range(len(list1))]
```

**Using zip function**

```
li = ['yes' if x == y else 'no' for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

**using map function**

```
li = list(map(lambda x, y: 'yes' if x == y else 'no', list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `set.intersection` as well:

```
list1 = ['M', 'AR0', 'I', 'K', 'Y']
list2 = ['M', 'AR0', 'IY', 'K', 'U']
intersection = set(list1).intersection(set(list2))
[print('Yes') if i in intersection else print('No') for i in list1]
```