# comparing nth element of a list with nth element of another list

Tags: python

Here is what I've been asked to do:

> Create a function named g(L1, L2) (arguments must be in that order) that takes in a pair of lists L1 and L2 with the same length, and returns zero if L1 and L2 have different lengths, and otherwise returns a list whose   -th entry is the greatest of either of the   -th elements L1 and L2, so that, for example:
>
> ```
> g( [10,8,6,4,2,0], [1,3,5,7,9,11] ) = [10,8,6,7,9,11]
> ```

This is what I've come up with:

```
def g(L1, L2):
    L = []
    if len(L1) != len(L2):
        return 0
    else: 
        if L1[0]>L2[0]:
            L.append(L1[0])
        else:
            L.append(L2[0])
    return L
```

However this only compares the first elements of the lists and I would like to compare all n-th elements of the lists. This is the part I'm a bit stuck on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73104327/how-to-compare-two-lists-which-have-strings-in-them-in-python

Comment: Research "list comprehensions" and the "max" and "zip" functions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so what's your question exactly? Or what do you need help with exactly? Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). See also [ask]. The first step would be to use a loop in some form or another; do you know how to do that? If you do, please show us what you tried that didn't work, and we can help you go from there. You can [edit] if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for every element in a list, you need to *iterate*. One method of doing so is a `for` loop using `range`, so let's do that.

Remember that a `return` will immediately exit the function, so an `else` after such a conditional isn't necessary.

```
def g(L1, L2):
  if len(L1) != len(L2):
    return 0

  L = []
  for i in range(len(L1)):
    if L1[i] > L2[i]:
      L.append(L1[i])
    else:
      L.append(L2[i])

  return L
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `zip`, list comprehension and a ternary to make the function a oneliner:

```py
def g(L1, L2):
    return 0 if len(L1) != len(L2) else [max(x, y) for x, y in zip(L1, L2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [while](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) loop:

```
def g(L1, L2):
    L = []
    while len(L) < len(L1) and len(L1) == len(L2):
        if L1[len(L)] > L2[len(L)]:
            L.append(L1[len(L)])
        else:
            L.append(L2[len(L)])
    return L or 0
```

Or you can use [ternary](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to check list's length equality and [map](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#map) to apply [max](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#max) function to every pair in [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#zip) of `L1` and `L2`

```
def g(L1,L2):return([*map(max,zip(L1,L2))],0)[len(L1)!=len(L2)]
```

Comment: This seems unnecessarily obfuscated.

Comment: A ternary seems more readable in this case, but using map would be appropriate.